# I have a large project, relies on GNU automake, want to add QT components, must I use qmake for everything now?

Tags: qt, qt4, g++

I have a large software project which uses aspects of OpenGL for visualisation. I want to add a GUI and was thinking of using QT. Now from what I understand, building QT stuff can get ugly unless one sticks to using the qmake command...

However, my project relies on the GNU tools for building (g++, autoconf, automake, etc., etc.). Must I therefore restructure my whole build process to use qmake just so that I can use a few small aspects of QT? I am very reluctant to do so given the size of the project.

As a thought, could I possibly (somehow) use qmake for the graphical components (i.e. qt-dependent stuff) only and continue to use my standard GNU build process (make, g++ etc.) for everything else?

Thanks,
Ben.

Comment: Isn't there a way to use autotools for Qt? Does KDE use qmake, for example? I thought it was using autotools.

Comment: @Sergey: KDE uses CMake, which generates makefiles on many systems (such as Linux).

Comment: Oh yes, and it's Qt, not QT. QT stands for Apple QuickTime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much head-scratching, I decided to compile the original code into a library using my original build process (but slightly modified to compile a library rather than a binary) and then compile the gui separately using qmake. This would then also link the gui in with the original library code. Not 100% ideal but works fine. Probably the biggest hurdle was converting some glut code into a QGLWidget...

Answer (score 6):

A quick Google search turned up [AutoTroll](http://tsunanet.net/autotroll/) and a [howto](http://qtnode.net/wiki/Qt_with_autotools).

Personally, I have used Qt without `qmake` before, but it was for a personal project, so I just used a (non-portable) Makefile.  I set a variable (`QT4DIR`, since `QTDIR` was used by Qt3) to point to where I installed Qt, then added `-L$(QT4DIR)/lib -lQtCore -lQtGui`, etc. to `LDFLAGS` and `-I$(QT4DIR)/include/QtCore`, `-I$(QT4DIR)/include/QtGui`, etc. to `CXXFLAGS`.  It looks like those links explain how to do something similar for autotools.

Edit:

To handle the MOC, I've added implicit rules like:

```
 moc_%.cc: %.h
     $(MOC) $< -o $@
```

And then make sure that all required `moc_*.cc` files are included in my `SOURCES`.  It's a bit of a pain to specify QObject-derived classes twice, but everything will get built.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel. Will try that. The main thing I'm concerned about is this 'meta-object-compiler' (moc) thing which by all accounts QT relies upon but which is handled automatically by qmake. But it does look like the second link make some reference to it...n.b. I'm not so interested in portability at this stage.

Comment: ...with regards to 'moc', I also found this which looks useful http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/moc.html

Comment: Updated my answer with a MOC implicit rule.

Comment: Thanks for the update...still scratching my head a little though. If I have my_qt.h and my_qt.cpp, do I have to essentially copy them so that I also have moc_my_qt.h and moc_my_qt.cpp?

Comment: Nope.  That implicit rule will *generate* `moc_my_qt.cpp` automatically from `my_qt.h`.  No need for a `moc_my_qt.h`, but `my_qt.h` must declare exactly one class derived from QObject that contains the `Q_OBJECT` macro, or else MOC will get all confused.

Comment: Thanks again, I'm just trying this now. I'm currently stuck on how to add the moc rule to my Makefile.am file..any idea?

Comment: I believe you can add the above implicit rule directly into `Makefile.am`.  The how-to linked above has a section on automake, and it includes how to add moc files to your sources list, too.

Comment: Thanks, but after trying this approach all day, I just couldn't get it to all click together. So I decided instead that I'd compile all my prior code to a shared library, meaning I can keep the original autotools process; I can then link this library in to a custom built gui when I invoke qmake